# Passing a class to sprintf

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions

Good morning.

I've got a class, which is technically just a wrapper about a char-array.
It allocates memory for the string upon it's construction and releases it upon it's destruction. That's not the problem.

The problem arises, whenever I want to pass it to any vararg function (for example sprintf)
My compiler throws me an error, stating that it can't copy a `non-trivial type`.

After a little Google search, it told me, that a 'trivial type' is any type, which can be copied with `memcpy`, doesn't have any constructors, etc.

Now my question: Is there any way to get the compiler to pass the internal char string with only writing the variable?

And example:

```
Wrapper Var("World");
sprintf(Buf, "Hello %s", Var);
```

After this call, it's supposed to be 'Hello World'.

It works, if I write (and call) any function, which accesses the internal stream (like `c_str()`, but that's not exactly the purpose of the class.
It's supposed to be a clean API, which can be passed around like a regular char string, just with the memory management functions.

I've tried:

```
operator char *() {
    return InternalString;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be getting called by `sprintf`.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `sprintf` and not `std::stringstream` (and providing a stream inserter method in your `Wrapper` class?

Comment: The `printf` function is from the C library, it knows nothing about classes, objects or operator overloading.

Comment: Can you put up the actual error message your compiler is returning?

Comment: Or for that matter, any particular reason to use this wrapper class instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @dreamlax It does a little bit more than just being a wrapper. (It actually escapes it for a mysql database). That's also the reason, why I didn't use std::string, since mysql_real_escape_string works best with chars. I'll look into stringstream though.

Comment: @legends2k It's: 'cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'class classname' through '...'.

Comment: @dreamlax Just to follow up on that 'stringstream' thing...I'm not too fond of the C++ streams. I've learned to use printf and it's relatives and it's hard letting go of something you know is useful.  But thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @ATaylor: I agree, I think streams are a horrible interface to formatted I/O, however as the saying goes, *When in Rome*. I asked a question a while ago about combining `sprintf` and `std::string` and the C++-purists made me regret asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit conversion operators won't work with variable arg functions like `sprintf()`, since the compiler doesn't know what type the object needs to be converted to. So in this case you'll need to use the `c_str()` function (or similar), or explicitly cast it using `static_cast<char*>(Var)`.

Comment: Hmm. I figured it'd be like this. That's a shame, but I guess none of us can help that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

in practice, adding a member function acting like 'c_str()' is the best solution
or you provide an approach to cast the type 'wrapper' to char*

Comment: Yeah, it would seem that way. Ah well, when life gives you lemons, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass non-POD object as arguments for variable argument functions.
Try to have a look at Boost Format, or use C++11 to write you own type safe sprintf function